# What is the difference between the infinity norm of a transfer function and the infinity norm of a matrix

Tags: normed-spaces, control-theory, robust-statistics

I am studying robust control system, and get confused with the following two definitions of infinity norm. ($G(j\omega)$ is the transfer function of a MIMO system)

[1] $$\left \| G \right \| _\infty = \max \limits _{1 \leq i \leq m} \sum _{j=1} ^n | g_{ij} |$$
[2] $$\left \| G \right \| _\infty = \sup \limits _{\omega} \bar \sigma (G(j\omega))$$

What is the difference between these two different definiation? I am wondering whether the definition [1] is just the infinity norm of the TF $G(j\omega)$ at a specified frequency $\omega_0 $.

Comment: The first is an induced matrix norm while the second is an operator norm. Note that  $\|G\|_{\infty}:=\sup_{v\neq 0}\frac{\|Gv\|_{\infty}}{\|v\|_{\infty}}$  and $\|G(s)\|_{\infty}:=\sup_{u\neq 0}\frac{\|y\|_2}{\|u\|_2}$ for a system with input $u$, output $y$ and t.f. $G(s)$ so they are not actually related to each other.

Comment: shouldn't operator norm and induced norm are the same thing? in Wikipediea, it says : If vector norms on Km and Kn are given (K is the field of real or complex numbers), then one defines the corresponding induced norm or operator norm on the space of m-by-n matrices as the following suprema:  \begin{aligned}\|A\|&=\sup\{\|Ax\|:x\in K^{n}{\mbox{ with }}\|x\|=1\}\\&=\sup \left\{{\frac {\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}}:x\in K^{n}{\mbox{ with }}x\neq 0\right\}.\end{aligned}

Comment: They are both induced. The first from the $\infty$-norm of a vector, the second from the 2-norm of a function.

Comment: It's just a case of unfortunate notation -- these are very different things. Basically think of the $\mathcal{H}^{\infty}$ norm as being defined on transfer functions or transfer matrices, with the standard matrix $\infty$-norm is just defined on constant matrices.